# jQuery Mobile and websockets with android

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, websocket

I need to implement something like this. I was searching over internet, and i found this http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets . Is it possible to avoid this restriction if i need to integrate jquery mobile with android (in android browser)?

---

I try to go on http://www.websocket.org/echo.html with my android 4.0 phone and android browser, and i am getting that websocket are supported... Are they really supported? Does someone have informations about this?

Comment: I just wrote a post about this. You can bridge the socket calls via a native socket connection. See below for details. http://chpeck.tumblr.com/post/37273036645/socket-io-with-android-webview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WebSocket via Flash fallback (https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js) with the builtin Android browser on devices that support (and have enabled) Flash.

You can use WebSocket natively on alternative Android browsers like Google Chrome for Mobile (full RFC6455), Firefox Mobile (full RFC6455) or Opera Mobile (Hixie-76 only)